# Run PHP over IIS on an external domain

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, windows-authentication

I need to connect to a remote MS sql-server, which allows connection only over Windows Authentication, using php. My actual setup is IIS10.0, PHP 7.5 and the latest SQLSRV driver for php.
The website is located in my local PC. If i set domain identity (e.g. EXTERNALDOMAIN\USER) in application pool identity, website is no longer running (error 503), probably because of no granted permission of external user for my local folder. How can i deal with this problem?

Comment: `probably because of no granted permission of external user for my local folder`...so have you tried granting such permission?

Comment: I have no idea how to add such user, since it is not present in my local pc.

Comment: Well you managed to add it to IIS, so I don't see why you can't set user permissions for it? Are you not able to search for it in the permissions box or something? How did you set it up in IIS exactly? Is your PC part of a domain which is federated with this external domain? If not then it's unclear how you'd ever expect the authentication to work. Maybe you need to work from a machine which is joined to the domain (or a federated domain).

Comment: In IIS i have just set a different identity in advanced settings of application, with user/password related to remote domain. My pc is part of another domain not even related with the external one, i just connect to remote network/domain over vpn (for example, i connect with SMSS using runas, giving external domain credentials). I think that for this reason i cannot change domain/workgroup in permission box, i see only my local accounts instead.

Comment: You need to talk to your domain administrators so as to understand better how user accounts can or cannot log on on a machine, and what alternative you might have. For example, if this machine is not somehow associated with that domain, you cannot set a user identity from that domain and force IIS to log it on (the direct cause of 503).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately domain administrator is on vacation and i have to wait! I'm asking only if it exists a sort of "runas /netonly" for php+iis combo, but i think there's no solution to this point, correct?

Comment: In addition to Lex Li said, you can also check event viewer to get error message about 503 error. Check stack trace to know which file or folder the application pool identity does not have read and write permissions for.